# Print value from foreach, for or while loop

Tags: php, loops

I'm trying to print a row for a table containing the information I receive within a loop. This does work, however, the array I loop has about 200 items, and it hangs until every item is checked. Is there a way I can print the row at each iteration ?
Sample code I use:

```
        foreach ($array_check as $dns) {
        if (checkdnsrr($dns. '.',"A")) {
            $ret = "<tr> 
                <td><span class='badge badge-important'><i class='icon-remove icon-white'></i></span></td>
                <td>$dns</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>option</td>
                </tr><br/>";
            echo $ret;
        } else {
            $ret = "<tr>
                <td><span class='badge badge-success'><i class='icon-ok icon-white'></i></span></td>
                <td>$dns</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>option</td>
                </tr><br/>";
            echo $ret;
        }
        flush();
        ob_flush();
        usleep(1000000);
    }
```

Any suggestions are appreciated, I've search around the internet a lot regarding this, most I find point to output_buffering which needs to be off and gzip also off.

I have both of them disabled but still hangs until it finishes before shows any output.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a little correction on your HTML: there's no need of a `<br>` after a `<tr>`. It is actually wrong, you shouldn't put anything different than `<tr>` inside a table body.

About your question, if I got it right you would like to print the output row by row, while the loop is performed, right? 
What you tried to do is very browser dependant, better change approach: request the data via AJAX, in your php script simply use:

```
$output = array();
foreach ($array_check as $dns) {
    $output[] = checkdnsrr($dns. '.', "A");
}
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($output);
```

Then parse the HTML on client side using javascript adding the timing you prefer, or maybe use JQuery and add also some fancy animations.

**EDIT**: I had forgotten about `checkdnsrr`, fixed it.

Comment: Indeed, this is what I'm working at the moment, seems like the issue can't be fixed normally from php.

Answer (score 0):

It takes time to display because you use usleep(1000000); to wait 1 second.

And instead of using if else to display the row with this or that class you could simply do:

```
    foreach ($array_check as $dns) {
        echo "<tr> 
            <td><span class='badge badge-".((checkdnsrr($dns. '.',"A"))?'important':success)."'><i class='icon-remove icon-white'></i></span></td>
            <td>$dns</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>option</td>
            </tr><br/>";
    flush();
    ob_flush();
    usleep(1000000);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, you didn't get my point, I'm using usleep to test exactly if it prints on each iteration ...